# Cross domain jquery json

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have tried tons of thing to get json data from another url with jQuery. I have working code in php, but dont have any idea how to do it in jquery.

PHP:

```
$skin = rawurlencode($market_hash_name);
$skin2 = str_replace('%0A', '', $skin);
$link = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=EU&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$skin2;
$json2 = file_get_contents($link);
$obj2 = json_decode($json2);
$mediumPrice = $obj2->median_price;
```

Example of jQuery that i have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=EU&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=AWP%20%7C%20Worm%20God%20(Factory%20New)',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.median_price);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: unless that url supports jsonp, you can't just point your ajax call at it. jsonp has very very strict syntax to work at all, and joe-random-url isn't going to cut it.

Comment: use a proxy either on your server or third party to get the data

Comment: what `code` do you have working in php? CURL, because you can ajax to your server, use the php code to get the data and then return it, like a proxy.  That is typically how its done.  Then there is no cross domain JSON in javascript to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a easy way around that is to create a Proxy, that is just a fancy word for saying have something else send and receive the data between the end points.

This can be as simple as using ajax to a PHP file on your server, from that PHP file using CURL to your endpoint, back to the output through echoing the return of the CURL script.

That way you can get around the restrictions on JavaScript.  You mention

> I have working code in php

So it should be relatively trivial to pipe the ajax call through that code and back.

Ok so instead of doing this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=EU&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=AWP%20%7C%20Worm%20God%20(Factory%20New)',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.median_price);
    }
});
```

Do this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://yoursever.com/proxy.php/?country=EU&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=AWP%20%7C%20Worm%20God%20(Factory%20New)',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.median_price);
    }
});
```

Then in `proxy.php` or whatever you chose to name it, use your working php code to make the call then simply return that data to the client through JSON as per normal AJAX.  Then you are technically calling the remote sever using PHP and don't have the cross domain issue.  But because you are using your sever as a Proxy you can still do it in real time.

Comment: I need to load my JSON data after the page is loaded and function has been executed by onClick and with my knowledge i cant load json data with php after the page is loaded, or can i?

Comment: Sure you can, you can submit a request to your own sever with JSON just the same as any other sever.  I think you miss the point